# In my profile the 'seen 1 min ago' statement

Tags: support

In the profile, where it says that it was last seen, it always says 'seen 1 min ago' because it counts the current look where I am looking at my own profile. This means I never get to see the last time it was looked at by anyone other than me at this very moment in which I am looking at it. Is there a fix planned for that or is it not for me but for admins to see that value? Thanks.

Comment: That's not what "seen 1 min ago" means.  Seen 1 minute ago means that you were seen on the site 1 minute ago, not that your profile was viewed 1 minute ago.  There isn't anything on the site that tells you when your own profile was last viewed by somebody else.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarifications and suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

The `seen x units ago` statement does not mean that *your profile* was seen `x units` ago; it means that **you** were seen `x units` ago.

Whenever you visit the site, vote, comment, answer/ask a question, etc., you are performing an action on the site that registers as a "visit." These "visits" are used for your consecutive day count (i.e. `visited x days, y consecutive`), which can award you badges ([Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast) and [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic)).

The only thing on your profile that relates to what *other people* see is "profile views," which tells you how many users have viewed your profile (obviously).